# What happens when multiple devices with different bluetooth versions connect to the same receiver?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

For example, a keyboard that supports v3.0 and a mouse that supports v4.2 with LE connect to the same Bluetooth receiver. Will the receiver default to the standard of the oldest device (v3.0) or will it be able to communicate with each device in its preferred protocol version?

Comment: Each connection is separate (separate connection stream) so that the faster device should use the faster service. Wireless works the same way:  "N" Wireless gives higher speed to an "N" computer but slower speed to a "G" computer. Same wireless.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. You should make it an answer!

Comment: Thank you and I have posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth and Wireless are very similar in nature.

Each connection is separate (separate connection stream) so that the faster device should use the faster service.

Wireless works the same way: "N" Wireless gives higher speed to an "N" computer but slower speed to a "G" computer. Same wireless.